# Converting Android App to Windows App using Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

Can a Android Hybrid App with some plugins written in Java and others imported from Cordova, be made windows phone complaint using Xamarin ?
Is there any such feature in VS 2015 from which conversion of android app to windows be made possible without much rework. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Xamarin will not allow you to automatically convert an app from one platform to another.

Microsoft has announced [Project Astoria](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/uwp-bridges/project-astoria) as part of Windows 10. This will enable Android apps to run as Windows Universal apps.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a Android Hybrid App with some plugins written in Java and others
>   imported from Cordova, be made windows phone complaint using Xamarin ?

No you cannot.

There are two ways to port Java code to C#.

The first way is to port the code manually.

The second porting methodology is to try and automate the process by using a code converter.